Pipeline exclude security vulnerabilities from flag warnAsError
I had a task of

Getting rid of all warnings out of our solution
In the validate pipeline treat all warnings as errors

I achieved this by adding msbuildArgs: '/warnAsError':
- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: ${{ parameters.projectPath }}
    vsVersion: '17.0'
    msbuildArgs: '/warnAsError'  
    logProjectEvents: false

Problem is that locally all warnings are gone, when the pipeline runs we get severity vulnerability warnings which also are now treated as errors (obvious previously was warnings). Because this task is now getting out of scope we decided to create a new task on the backlog to solve the vulnerability warnings.
My question is how can I use /warnAsError flag except on these vulnerability warnings. Please note I don't want to suppress them, I still want the warnings, but /warnAsError flag should not count for them.

Perhaps editing AnalyzerConfig might help? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/suppress-warnings#disable-the-rule

By vulnerability warning, did you mean nuget audit warnings in the nuget restore step?
